Does every page wrapped in Mantine's AppShell become client rendered?
I am working on a project using NextJs and Mantine, and I'd like to take advantage of Mantine's AppShell to structure my pages.Since AppShell wraps around the entire page and Mantine's components are client-side rendered., I'm wondering if the entire page becomes client-side rendered as a result.
